# Finding the expected number of flips needed for a coin having probability $p$ of landing on heads

Tags: probability, expected-value

> A coin, having probability $p$ of landing on heads and probability of $q=1-p$ of landing on tails. It is continuously flipped until at least one head and one tail have been flipped.
>   a) Find the expected number of flips needed.

This is not part of a homework assignment. I am studying for a final and don't understand the professors solutions. Since this is clearly geometric, I would think the solution would be:
$$E(N)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ip^{n-1}q+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}iq^{n-1}p=\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}.$$
However, I am completely wrong. The answer is
$$E(N)=p\left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)+q\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right).$$
For example, consider we flip for heads first. Then we have
$$E(N\mid H)=p+p\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}np^{n-1}q.$$
I am not sure why this makes sense. I am not entirely sure why we have an added $1$ and a factored $p$, $q$. Could someone carefully explain why it makes sense that this is the right answer?

Comment: It's all a question of the first toss.  If it is $H$ then you just get one more than  the expected time to get a $T$, if it is $T$ then you just get one more than the expected time to get $H$.  Your method is incorrect because the expected number of tosses needed to get one of the two is $1$.

Comment: In both the title and first paragraph it appears there is $0$ chance of landing tails, so you will wait forever.

Comment: Note:  your sums are hard to follow.  What's $n$?  The upper limit of the sums should be $\infty$, the exponent of the probability ought to be a simple function of $i$.  Done correctly, your method ought to work (though it's easier to do it the other way).

Answer (score 5):

If you get a head with probability $p$ then the expected number of throws is $1+E(X)$ where $X$ is a geometric distribution requiring a tail to be thrown with probability $q$ so $1+E(X)=1+\frac1q$. Similarly if you throw a tail with probability $q$ then the expected number of throws is $1+E(Y)$ where $Y$ is a geometric distribution requiring a head to be thrown with probability $p$ so $1+E(Y)=1+\frac1p$. This means that the overall expected number of throws is
$$p\left(1+\frac1q\right)+q\left(1+\frac1p\right)$$
because there is a probability $p$ that the expected number of throws is given by $1+E(X)$ and probability $q$ that it is given by $1+E(Y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be the time of the first head, and $Y$ the time of the first tail, and $W$ the first time when a head and a tail has been flipped.

You are right in assuming that $E[X]=\frac{1}{p}$ and $E[Y]=\frac{1}{q}$, But you are wrong in assuming that $W=X+Y$, that's simply not true, actually $W=\max(X,Y)$.

A possible approach. Let $A$ be the indicator variable of the event: "first coin was a head" (hence $X=1$).

Then use $$E[W]=E[E[W | A ]] = P(A=1) E[W|A=1]+P(A=0) E[W|A=0]=\\=p(E[Y]+1)+q(E[X]+1)$$